# OnDatabound event in Gridview not working on Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a column that has various status' that change color depending on the letter.

For example if the letter is 'R' then the cell is red, if 'G' then green, etc...

The problem is this initially works but then when the user edits the record and changes the status the color doesn't update to the corresponding letter.

Please take a look at the code and let me know what I am doing wrong:

```
 if (dataItem != null)
            {
                var label = dataItem["Status"].FindControl("StatusID") as Label;

                if (label != null)
                {

                    var item = dataItem;
                    var text = label.Text;

                    switch (text)
                    {
                        case "G":
                            item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Green;

                            break;
                        case "Y":
                            item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                        case "O":
                            item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Orange;
                            break;
                        case "M":
                            item["Status"].BackColor = Color.SaddleBrown;
                            break;
                        case "R":
                            item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case " ":
                            item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Gray;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Update**
Now when I go to edit the record some of the records don't allow me to update them.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="StatusDDL" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#
Bind("Status")%>' DataTextField="Status" Width="100px" Skin="Metro" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px" DataValueField="Status" DataSourceID="StatusFilter" TabIndex="7" AppendDataBoundItems="True"></telerik:RadComboBox>                     
</EditItemTemplate>


<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="StatusID" Text='<%# Bind("Status")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you binding once again after editing is completed?

Comment: @Bharadwaj, no. Should I call the TestGrid.Rebind(); method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my solution:

```
 if (dataItem == null) return;

    switch (dataItem["Status"].Text)
    {
        case "G":
            dataItem["Status"].BackColor = Color.Green;

            break;
        case "Y":
            dataItem["Status"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        case "O":
            dataItem["Status"].BackColor = Color.Orange;
            break;
        case "M":
            dataItem["Status"].BackColor = Color.SaddleBrown;
            break;
        case "R":
            dataItem["Status"].BackColor = Color.Red;
            break;
        case " ":
            dataItem["Status"].BackColor = Color.Gray;
            break;
    }
```